# (Python)How to rotate an image so that a feature becomes vertical?

Tags: python, arrays, image, rotation, 2d

I would like to rotate an image (such as the one below) in a way that one of its features (which resembles a line) becomes vertical. However, I can't seem to find a way to programmatically do it in Python. 
[Example_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdirN.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rotation itself can be done by the [scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html) operation.

The following first part is solving the issue for the example scenario in the original question (having one elongated data blob), see below for a more general (but slower) approach. Hope this helps!

---

**First Approach:** To find the axis and with that the angle of your line I suggest to use a PCA on the non-zero values:

```
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import rotate
#from skimage.transform import rotate ## Alternatively
from sklearn.decomposition.pca import PCA ## Or use its numpy variant
import numpy as np

def verticalize_img(img):
    """
    Method to rotate a greyscale image based on its principal axis.

    :param img: Two dimensional array-like object, values > 0 being interpreted as containing to a line
    :return rotated_img: 
    """# Get the coordinates of the points of interest:
    X = np.array(np.where(img > 0)).T
    # Perform a PCA and compute the angle of the first principal axes
    pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(X)
    angle = np.arctan2(*pca.components_[0])
    # Rotate the image by the computed angle:
    rotated_img = rotate(img,angle/pi*180-90)
    return rotated_img
```

As usually this function could also be written as one-liner:

```
rotated_img = rotate(img,np.arctan2(*PCA(2).fit(np.array(np.where(img > 0)).T).components_[0])/pi*180-90)
```

And here is an example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# Example data:
img = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
                [0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,1]])
# Or alternatively a straight line:
img = np.diag(ones(15))
img = np.around(rotate(img,25))

# Or a distorted blob:
from sklearn import cluster, datasets
X, y = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers = [[0,0]])
distortion = [[0.6, -0.6], [-0.4, 0.8]]
theta = np.radians(20)
rotation = np.array(((cos(theta),-sin(theta)), (sin(theta), cos(theta))))
X =  np.dot(np.dot(X, distortion),rotation)
img = np.histogram2d(*X.T)[0] # > 0 ## uncomment for making the example binary

rotated_img = verticalize_img(img)
# Plot the results
plt.matshow(img)
plt.title('Original')
plt.matshow(rotated_img)
plt.title('Rotated'))
```

Note that for highly noisy data or images with no clear orientation this method will come up with arbitrary rotations.

And here is an example output:

[image]
[image]

---

**Second Approach:** Ok after clarification of the actual task in a more complicated setting (see comments) here a second approach based on template matching:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import rotate
from scipy.signal import correlate2d#, fftconvolve
# Data from CSV file:
img = pandas.read_csv('/home/casibus/testdata.csv')
# Create a template:
template = np.zeros_like(img.values)
template[:,int(len(template[0])*1./2)] = 1
suggested_angles = np.arange(0,180,1) # Change to any resolution you like
overlaps = [np.amax(correlate2d(rotate(img,alpha,reshape=False),template,mode='same')) for alpha in suggested_angles]
# Determine the angle resulting in maximal overlap and rotate:
rotated_img = rotate(img.values,-suggested_angles[np.argmax(overlaps)])
plt.matshow(rotated_img)
plt.matshow(template)
```

[image: rotated image]
[image: template]

Comment: Dear Jojo,
thank you very much for your detailed answer. It seems to solve the problem but It fails for noisy data (as you mention), which is most of my data unfortunately.

Comment: Dear Bella_Ciao_gr, could you provide an example array?

Comment: Thank you for your interest, Jojo. Here is a link to my file:
https://ufile.io/jnm7q

Comment: Ok, that of course is a very different situation. Here you have multiple stripes and to get my function to work you would need to extract one of the stripes first. Here is a very practical approach: I suggest to use a template (i.e. a vertical line image) and rotate your data as long as the overlap (in terms of the peak value scipy.signal.correlation2d) is maximized. This gives you the angle. I might find time to work it out for you later in case you have problems.

Comment: Here you go! I did not test it for different examples, there could be a mistake in the way how it is rotated in the end. In that case try to remove the minus. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, it works! 
However, let me ask you: Why did you choose to open it from a csv file?
Because I tried opening it from a txt as ndarray and I ended up with a not so good rotation.

Comment: That is just because originally I was looking at your data in LibreOffice Calc and from there I stored it as a CSV, because I knew that pandas can candle it straight forward. The method I suggested may not depend on the file format. I guess that you had an issue during the import to the ndarray?! You can check that by just plotting the imported image. Does it look the same as expected? If I find time later, I can try to do it your way. If you like my solution I invite you to accept it ;-)

Comment: Probably there was something wrong during my conversion to .csv 
but now everything is perfect! Thank you for all your advice!

Comment: Glad that I could help!